# How to install a python package in a zip file from a self hosted location using setup.py?

Tags: python, pip, dependencies, setup.py

I have a package called "my_package" which is in a zip called "my_package.zip" and is on a custom location called "http://my.webaddress.com/software/my_package.zip" (not the real address of course).

I am able to install this package using the following pip command:
`pip install http://my.webaddress.com/software/my_package.zip`

But now I want to create a setup.py file for another project that depends on this package. So the file "my_other_package/setup.py" contains this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='my_other_package',
  version='1.0.1',
  py_modules=['my_other_package'],
  install_requires=[
      'scipy',
      'numpy',
      'my_package',
  ],
  dependency_links=[
  'http://my.webaddress.com/software/my_package.zip#egg=my_package'
  ]
)
```

But then I get the error:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement my_package (from my_other_package==1.0.1) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for my_package (from my_other_package==1.0.1)
```

How can I get this working?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+dependency_links

Comment: The trick was to add "--process-dependency-links".